# .get() Url is not what i expect

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying angular.js for the first time.
I have my rest service configured the following way:

```
get('/api/users') //returns a JSON Array with all the users
get('/api/users/:id') //returns a JSON object with the requested ID
```

My angular Controller is set up like this:

```
UserCtrl.factory('User', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});

var EditCtrl = function($scope, $location, $routeParams, User){
    var id = $routeParams._id;
    $scope.user = User.get({id: id});
};
```

My problem is that when i run

```
User.get({id: id})
```

the URL requested is:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users?id=389498473294
```

I want it to be

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users/389498473294
```

I can do it using `$http`, but i think `.get()` should be able to do it...

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define the default value for the id parameter with a prefixed @, that means that the value must be taken from the object passed as parameter to the call. In a get call there is no object sent, so the id parameter is assigned the null value.
Being the id parameter already assigned, the value you pass is appended as a query parameter.
For an explanation of this look at [angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) under the Usage/Param defaults paragraph.
The correct way to declare the service should be:

> UserCtrl.factory('User', function($resource) {
>       return $resource('/api/users/:id', { id: '' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } }); });

Comment: i don't think you understood my question. I want to make a GET Request, but with no query string, using Rest i want http://localhost:8080/api/users/389498473294

Comment: I understood your question, the query string is generated by angular, have you tried the code modification I suggested?

Comment: yes i did. It goes without the query string, but it doesn't append the id to the path

Comment: Can you create a plunker to make some test?

Comment: the code is exactly the one i have in the question. i don't have much time to make the plunker

Comment: I've done this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1AdvImCjtRJbsD4FzafT?p=preview). You can try it opening the browser Javascript console, you will see exactly the URL you want, I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24324/discussion-between-remigio-and-andre-alcada-padez)

Comment: I'm sorry but i really had to leave, i was in a meeting that lasted until one hour ago. I'll have a look at your plunker. thank you

Comment: yep, it is working. Thanks, i don't know why it didn't work the first time i tried. sorry about that